# Accessing Jenkins API from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, jsonp, cors

I'm trying to retrieve information about one job build from the api rest provided by Jenkins with Angularjs.

Jsonp is actually disabled on Jenkins:

[Jenkins Security Advisory 2013-02-16](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2013-02-16)

so this piece of code can't work:

```
var url = 'http://jenkins-server:8080/job/job-name/api/json?jsonp=callback';
$http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

throw:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Cors is not enabled by default... to be honest I can't find the way to install this plugins:

- https://github.com/algal/cors
- https://github.com/jhinrichsen/cors-plugin

and this code can't work as well

```
var url = 'http://jenkins-server:8080/job/job-name/api/json'
$http({url: url, method: 'GET'}).success(function(data){console.log(data)})
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? CORS isn't supported below IE10.

Comment: @GrantByrne it has partial support in IE8 and IE9 via XDomainRequest

Comment: I'm using chrome. IE sucks ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this CORS filter plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin

Or you can host your Angular app on the Jenkins server using the User Content mechanism:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/User+Content

Comment: what are the values we need to give for access-control-allow-header and access-control-expose-headers here ?, if I am trying for get request from angular. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a plugin now for whitelisting JSON requests...Just go to the plugins, and search for JSON.

The Secure Access plugin.

Answer (score 0):

@Mauro, starting with Jenkins 1.537 you can implement "**[jenkins.security.SecureRequester](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/security/SecureRequester.html)**" and allow the json request to work.

You just have to implement the method **[permit(StaplerRequest req, Object bean)](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/security/SecureRequester.html#permit%28org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest,%20java.lang.Object%29)** and have your validations there and just return true (based on your validation result) to allow the request.

Once you done that you can simply use the first code snipped you have mentioned in your question.

Example SecureRequester Implementation : -

```
import hudson.Extension;
import jenkins.security.SecureRequester;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.StaplerRequest;

@Extension
public class AllowRequest implements SecureRequester {

    public boolean permit(StaplerRequest req, Object bean) {

        // A method to validate the request and return the appropriate result
        return YOUR_VALIDATION_METHOD(req,bean); 
    }

    private boolean YOUR_VALIDATION_METHOD(StaplerRequest req, Object bean) {
        // validation goes here
    }

}
```

You need to build this as a plugin and install it in you Jenkins setup to work.